# Interchange of sum an product in partition function for fermions

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, partition-function

On page 87 of Kittel’s *Elementary Statistical Physics,* it is claimed for fermions and the grand canonical ensemble:

$$Z
= \sum\limits _{\{n_{i}\}}\prod\limits _{i}\exp\left((\mu-\epsilon_{i}) \frac{n_{i}}{\tau}\right)
= \prod\limits _{i}\sum\limits _{n_{i}=0,1}\exp\left((\mu-\epsilon_{i}) \frac{n_{i}}{\tau}\right).$$

Where $\{n_{i}\}$ denotes the allowed values for $n_i$.
Introducing $x_i=\exp\left((\mu-\epsilon_{i}) / \tau\right)$, this becomes:

$$Z
=\sum\limits _{\{n_{i}\}}\prod\limits _{i}x_i^{n_i}
=\prod\limits _{i}\sum\limits _{n_{i}=0,1}x_i^{n_i}$$

However, in a simple example with two fermions and three different states with energies $\epsilon_1$, $\epsilon_2$, and $\epsilon_3$, there is a difference:

Left sum-product:
$$\sum\limits _{\{n_{i}\}}\prod\limits _{i}x_i^{n_i}
= x_1^0x_2^0x_3^0+x_1^1x_2^0x_3^0+x_1^0x_2^1x_3^0+x_1^0x_2^0x_3^1+x_1^1x_2^1x_3^0+x_1^1x_2^0x_3^1+x_1^0x_2^1x_3^1\\
=1+x_1+x_2+x_3+x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3.$$

Right product-sum:
$$\prod\limits _{i}\sum\limits _{n_{i}=0,1}x_i^{n_i}\\
=x_1^0x_2^0x_3^0+x_1^1x_2^0x_3^0+x_1^0x_2^1x_3^0+x_1^0x_2^0x_3^1+x_1^1x_2^1x_3^0+x_1^1x_2^0x_3^1+x_1^0x_2^1x_3^1+x_1^1x_2^1x_3^1\\
=1+x_1+x_2+x_3+x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_3.$$

In the second term, there occurs the additional product $x_1x_2x_3$. Where is my error in counting the states?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by “two fermions”?  In the grand canonical ensemble there is no fixed number of fermions.  Thus  $x^1_1x^1_2x^1_3$ is certainly allowed in your LH sum.

Answer (score 1):

Since we deal with fermions, any of the three states can be occupied or empty. This gives us $2^3=8$ different states, with occupation numbers $(0,0,0)$, $(1,0,0)$ and so on. The state $(1,1,1)$ is missing from the first sum for unclear reason.

Comment: Thanks, but in my example, at most 2 particels are distributed over 3 possible states. So, how should the state (1,1,1) be possible? Or is there a gross misconception on my part?

Answer (score 0):

I probably misunderstood the text! This example with only 2 particles for 3 states is not reasonable in the grand canonical ensemble. There is always a reservoir and this fills up the states of the system as far as just possible. In this case with 3 states a maximum of 3 particles is possible and necessary. The summation has to include all occupations, i.e. 0, 1, 2 and 3 particles. So also the $x_1x_2x_3$ product belongs to the sum.